# How to get changeset during a period in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I can use liquibase to change my database's schema, it's good.
But I need to get the changeset during a period, for example

```
1/1: add table1 => 1.0
1/10: add table2
1/18: alter table1 => 2.0
1/21: alter table2 
1/28: add table3 => 3.0
```

If I want to get a changeset (SQL command) from 1/10~1/28 or 1/18~1/21, is it possible?

[Update] Thanks for Mark's reply, I add version in above changeset in our development environment. And when our production database is in 1.0 and I want to upgrade to 2.0 (or 3.0) directly but just want use liquibase to generate SQL command and run it manually.

Rollback has a problem that if I rollback my development database, I need to re-create the data already on it. Is there any suggestion for it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the [command line documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/command_line).

To generate SQL based on date the only way I think it can be done is as follows:

```
liquibase rollbackToDate <date/time> 
liquibase tag <version so can rollback here again>
liquibase updateSQL > keepUpdate.sql
liquibase update
```

## Update

What you're attempting to do (use SQL to update production) is a common use-case that liquibase is designed to support. It's one of my favourite features.

Problem is.... In an ideal world you should be able to blow-away you dev database and start from scratch. Obviously you don't have liquibase changesets to manage your data , so need to consider some alternatives....

### Approach 1: Create a new DEV database

Run a SQL query and establish how many changsets there are on your development DB:

```
SELECT ORDEREXECUTED, DATEEXECUTED, ID, FILENAME, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS 
FROM DATABASECHANGELOG 
ORDER BY ORDEREXECUTED
```

Analyze the dates and establish how many chnagesets would take you back from version 3.0 to 2.0 (2 changesets) and 1.0 (4 changesets)

Create a fresh database and apply your liquibase changesets, bring your schema up to revision 3.0

```
liquibase update
```

To create the SQL for version 2.0 -> 3.0 upgrade

```
liquibase rollbackCount 2
liquibase updateSQL         > upgrade-2_0-3_0.sql
liquibase futureRollbackSQL > rollback-2_0-3_0.sql
```

And create the SQL for version 1.0 -> 3.0 upgrade

```
liquibase rollbackCount 2
liquibase updateSQL         > upgrade-1_0-3_0.sql
liquibase futureRollbackSQL > rollback-1_0-3_0.sql
```

### Approach 2: Use dbunit to save datasets

Another really useful tool for database management is [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/)

The following article explains how liquibase and dbunit could be used together to migrate databases:

- http://www.poornerd.com/2010/12/07/database-migration-with-liquibase-and-dbunit/

The two tools are complementary. In your case perhaps you could periodically save snaphots of your development data and use this to repopulate development or test databases (Obviously a dataset is sensitive to the version of a db schema, so some care is required)